# Want to get distinct records in hits section from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I want to get all the distinct records as per "departmentNo" .
Please check the below Index Data : (it is dummy data.)

```
  {'departmentNo': 1, 'departmentName': 'Food', 'departmentLoc': "I1", "departmentScore": "5", "employeeid" : 1, "employeeName": "vijay", ...}
    {'departmentNo': 1, 'departmentName': 'Food', 'departmentLoc': "I1", "departmentScore": "5", "employeeid" : 2, "employeeName": "rathod", ...}
    {'departmentNo': 2, 'departmentName': 'Non-Food', 'departmentLoc': "I2", "departmentScore": "6", "employeeid" : 3, "employeeName": "ajay", ...}
    {'departmentNo': 2, 'departmentName': 'Non-Food', 'departmentLoc': "I2", "departmentScore": "6", "employeeid" : 4, "employeeName": "kamal", ...}
    {'departmentNo': 1, 'departmentName': 'Food', 'departmentLoc': "I1", "departmentScore": "5", "employeeid" : 5, "employeeName": "rahul", ...}
```

I want the below output.

```
{'departmentNo': 1, 'departmentName': 'Food', 'departmentLoc': "I1", "departmentScore": "5", "employeeid" : 1, "employeeName": "vijay", ...}
{'departmentNo': 2, 'departmentName': 'Non-Food', 'departmentLoc': "I2", "departmentScore": "6", "employeeid" : 3, "employeeName": "ajay", ...}
```

I was trying to get data in hits section. But didn't found the answer.
So I tried with aggeration. Used below query

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "Group_By_Dept": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "departmentNo"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got the data by the above query. But I want all the distinct data and they should support pagination + sorting.
In elastic 6.0 we could use bucket_sort , but I am using 5.6.7.So I can't use bucket_sort.

So Can I do it in any other way.?
If I could get data in hits's section then it will be good.

(I don't want to change my index mapping. Actually here i have added dummy mapping. but usecase is same.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using [field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-request-collapse.html):

```
{
  "query": { ... },
  "from": 153,
  "size": 27,
  "collapse": {
    "field": "departmentNo"
  }
}
```

This will leave only one document for each repeating value in such field. You can control which document it would be using standard sort (i.e. document with highest sort value among collapsed would be returned).

Please note that there is additional functionality called inner hits, which you may want to use in the future - be aware that it multiplies document fetches and negatively affects performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @Etki
But pagination is not working. if I have 19 documents and from that 19, 15 are distinct. then 
when I do from =0 and size =5 then it should return 5 . and when I do from =1, size =5 then it should have returned next 5 distinct records. (But it is not returning)

Comment: I am not able to understand how pagination works with collapse

Comment: @user3432036 `from` is not a page number, it's an offset from start. If you need page number 2 with size 5, then you need to set `from` as `(pageNumber - 1) * size`, i.e. 5.

Comment: I am not using inerhits. I am just using collapsing.
So will it give any load on performance . because In my application, I have 1 million records. 

So I am just worried about performance.

Comment: is there any way to get the count of collapsing documents.

Comment: is there any way to get the count of collapsing documents without aggs ?
I mean to say in collapsing only .
Like : as per the above data.
- Department 1 has 3 docs.
- Department 2 has 2 docs. 
we are getting first record only, so can we get the first record with count.
{
  _source: { ... }
   count : 3
}

Comment: this may be done with inner_hits, but be aware that will put additional load even if you set size=0. it's easier to do with aggregation.